# How do I create a dictionary within another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

Right now I'm making a python program that takes names and stats and records them. To do this I am attempting to create a nested dictionary that looks something like this example.

```
playerData = {"Jack": {"strength": 10, "intelligence": 5}, "John": {"strength": 8, "intelligence": 10}}
```

My problem arises when I try to make it. I have my program structured to first create a list of names, and then a list of stat categories, and I'm trying to create a dictionary within a dictionary to create it. I have a function called collectPlayerAttributes that creates a list of stat categories, an example being

```html
["strength", "intelect", "charisma"]
```

. What I'm trying to do is pull the values from that list and enter them as keys into the dictionary playerData. Using the example list from earlier this would look something like

```html
{"Jack": {"strength": 10, "intelect": 5, "charisma": 8}}
```

The values attached to the keys are just placeholders, but in the end I'm planning to do something along the lines of

```html
input("What is Jack's strength? ")
```

and put the result there. My code so far is

```
playerData = {}
y = 0
for i in players:
  playerData[str(players[y])] = {#What goes here?}
  y += 1
```

Comment: We have little idea what your "stat list" is.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).

Comment: https://repl.it/@jreesebot/PerformanceTask#main.py

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: I have a function called collectPlayerAttributes that creates a list of stat categories, an example being ["strength", "intelect", "charisma"]. What I'm trying to do is pull the values from that list and enter them as keys into the dictionary playerData. Using the example list from earlier this would look something like {"Jack": {"strength": 10, "intelect": 5, "charisma": 8}}

Comment: Ok, so for `strength`, where does the example value `10` come from?

Comment: Again, your **question** needs to be self-contained.  Critical updates go into the question, not comments.  Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: The values attached to the keys are just placeholders, but in the end I'm planning to do something along the lines of input("What is Jack's strength? ") and put the result there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to create a `dict` where all players have an entry, you can create an empty `dict` for each of them:

```py
playerData = {i:{} for i in players}
```

If you then ask the user for a `strength` value you can do this:

```py
def updatePlayerAttribute(playerData, name, attribute):
    value = input(f'What is the {attribute} of {name}?')
    playerData[name][attribute] = value

name = "Jack"
attribute = "strength"
updatePlayerAttribute(playerData, name, attribute)
print(playerData)
```